# Chinese Text Display in QT Embedded Linux?

Tags: qt

I am using below code to display chinese text on click of a button , its working fine in Windows but when i try in Embedded device it show some junk values.
I am using "Batang" Font .
This font is installed in my Embedded device.

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
      QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
      QString qString1 = tr("鳶尾花");
      QByteArray byteArray = qString1.toUtf8();
      const char* cString = byteArray.data();
      QString qString2 = QString::fromUtf8(cString);
      QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName(cString));
      ui->txtFirstname->setText(qString2);
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved using :

```
 QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("GB18030"));
```

Big5 was not giving me correct result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different encoding and not UTF8 depends on the characters you will be using. Hope this helps.

- Guobiao is mainly used in Mainland China and Singapore. All Guobiao standards are prefixed by GB, the latest version is GB18030 which is a one, two or four byte encoding.
- Big5, used in Taiwan, Hong Kong and Macau, is a one or two byte encoding.
- Unicode, with the set of CJK Unified Ideographs.

Read this for more info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/codec-big5.html because the characters u use seem to be Big5 encoding characters
A tutorial can be found here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html

Comment: Which Encoding should i use ?

Comment: Code Sample pls. How to use this Big5 ?

Comment: A tutorial with some samples can be found here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextcodec.html I see that you need a specific codec to do so, but all information can be found there. (it's not my area of expertise)

Answer (score 1):

When you added the line

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName(cString));
```

you probably thought the following overload:

> [QTextCodec * QTextCodec::codecForName ( const QByteArray & name ) [static]](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextcodec.html#codecForName)

would try to find the best codec for the characters in the byte array you supplied.

However, this function tries to find the codec which has a name closest to the value you supplied, so you would have to do something like

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("Big5"));
```

instead.

Have you tried leaving out that line? You are already setting the text codec a few lines above anyway.